# Add Qt socket code for this app to enable chat between two PCs

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Can Anyone help me with this code? How can i add P2P chat code to this program?
I want to be able to chat between two PCs over a LAN

[image]

```
import sys, os
import socket 

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,
  QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QFileDialog,QMessageBox, QMenuBar)

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.Qt import QPushButton, QTextEdit, QMessageBox

class myApp (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.main_text      =       QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
    self.send_box       =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.connect_btn    =       QtWidgets.QPushButton('Connect', self)
    self.browse_btn     =       QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse',self)
    ip_add_box          =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    port_box            =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)




    self.main_text.setGeometry(25, 30, 360, 350)
    self.send_box.setGeometry(25, 400, 360, 60)
    ip_add_box.setGeometry(25, 530, 150, 30)
    port_box.setGeometry(180, 530, 90,30)
    self.connect_btn.setGeometry(25, 500, 70, 25)
    self.browse_btn.setGeometry(100,500,70,25)

    self.setGeometry(200,100,400,580)
    self.setWindowTitle('My Application')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

    # CODE BLOCK FOR EVENTS
    self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)      # EnterPressed Event for SendBox LineEdit
    self.connect_btn.clicked.connect(self.connectNet)       # Socket Connect event for the connect Button        
    self.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.BrowseFile)        # Browse file connect event for Browse Button


    self.show()

def sendData(self):
    self.main_text.append( self.send_box.text() )
    self.send_box.clear()
def connectNet(self):
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 12345
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = (host, port)
    print ("Connecting to %s port %s" % server_address)
    sock.connect(server_address)

    try: 
        message = "Test message. This will be echoed"
        print ("Sending %s" % message)
        sock.sendall(message)
        # Look for the response
        amount_received = 0
        amount_expected = len(message)
        while amount_received < amount_expected:
            data = sock.recv(16)
            amount_received += len(data)
            print ("Received: %s" % data)
    finally:
        print ("Closing connection to the server")
        sock.close()

def BrowseFile (self):
    filePath    =   QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)






if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = myApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc 
can you help with this please?

Comment: Fixed obvious code misformatting.

Comment: check this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-network-chat-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this. Client side is here

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

class Client(QtWidgets.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Client, self).__init__(parent)

    self.main_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
    self.main_text.setReadOnly(True)
    self.send_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.send_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send", self)
    self.browse_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Browse", self)
    # EVENT FOR SEND BUTTON
    self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.sendData)

    self.server_ip = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.server_ip.setPlaceholderText("IP address")
    self.port_address = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.port_address.setPlaceholderText("port")

    self.userName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.userName.setPlaceholderText("username")

    self.connectButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Connect",self)
    #Connect Button EVENT
    self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.connection)
    self.connectButton.setDefault(True)

    self.setGeometry(400,50,500,600)
    self.main_text.setGeometry(25,50,450,400)
    self.send_box.setGeometry(25,470,450,40)
    self.send_button.setGeometry(385,520,90,30)
    self.browse_btn.setGeometry(25,520,100,30)
    self.server_ip.setGeometry(150,10,130,25)
    self.port_address.setGeometry(300,10,70,25)
    self.connectButton.setGeometry(385,10,90,25)
    self.userName.setGeometry(25,10,120,25)


    #NetworkInput
    self.socket = QtNetwork.QTcpSocket(self)
    self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.readData)
    self.socket.error.connect(self.displayError)

def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.socket.disconnectFromHost()

def connection(self):
    self.socket.connectToHost(self.server_ip.text(), int(self.port_address.text()))
    if self.socket.waitForConnected(1000):
        self.user = self.userName.text()
        self.send("login %s" % self.user)
        self.connectButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.send_button.setDefault(True)
        self.send_box.setFocus()
        #self.setWindowTitle("<%s>" % self.user)
def readData(self):
    message = self.socket.readLine().data().decode("utf-8")
    self.main_text.append(message)

def send(self, message):
    self.socket.write(message.encode("utf-8"))

def sendData(self):
    message = "say %s" % (self.send_box.text())
    self.send(message)
    self.send_box.clear()
    self.send_box.setFocus()

def displayError(self):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Connection", "Connection error")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   client = Client()
   sys.exit(client.exec_())
```

Comment: But I still need help with the Browse button and file transfer if any one can help would be highly appreciated.